# Custom Function for Formula using Substitute

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula that I am having to use to strip out certain characters from another cell. For example, cell `C8` might contain something like: `A/CB.PR.01-AB`
Currently I use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C8,"/",""),".",""),"-","")," ","")
```

The result would then be `ACBPR01AB`. This is all fine and well but I can never remember the above formula and have to keep finding it and copying it over. I'm thinking that I could possibly create a VBA Function that would run this formula without me having to type it all in. So for example instead of the above I could just type `=WBSReplace(C8)` and the result would be the same as typing the full formula.

I'd also like to be able to run the function on any workbook and not have it restricted to just the workbook I am in.

Answer (score 3):

**[Example 1: ParamArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163323/custom-function-for-formula-using-substitute/51163736#51163736)**

This is an ideal case for a [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/paramarray) type parameter arguement. This allows for a virtually limitless number of characters or text strings to remove without passing in an array.

```
Function getRidOf(str As String, ParamArray dels())
    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(dels) To UBound(dels)
        str = Replace(str, dels(i), vbNullString, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    Next i

    getRidOf = str
End Function
```

Example:

```
=getRidOf(C8, "/",".","-"," ")      'result: ACBPR01AB
```

Note that the vbTextCompare makes the replacement non-case-sensitive. For a case-sensitive replacement, use vbBinaryCompare.

**[Example 2: RegEx.Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163323/custom-function-for-formula-using-substitute/51163736#51163736)**

This example may be easier to use for a long list of removal characters as it simply strips anything that isn't an uppercase letter or a number. It should be especially helpful to remove 'special' or unicode characters.

```
Function getRidOf2(str As String)
    Static rgx As Object

    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "[^A-Z0-9]"

        If .test(str) Then
            str = .Replace(str, vbNullString)
        End If
    End With

    getRidOf2 = str
End Function
```

Example:

```
=getRidOf2(C8)      'result: ACBPR01AB
```

**[Putting it into Practice with the Selection Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163323/custom-function-for-formula-using-substitute/51163736#51163736)**

After putting this sub procedure into a public module code sheet, select one or more cells, full columns, full rows or the entire worksheet then run this sub procedure through Alt+F8 or assign it to a hot-key combination.

```
sub stripThis()
    dim rng as range

    for each rng in intersect(selection, selection.parent.usedrange)
        rng = getRidOf2(rng.value2)
        'or the other one
        'rng = getRidOf(rng.value2, "/",".","-"," ")
    next rng

end sub
```

Comment: Wow. Really impressed with the quick responses and options provided by all. I'll take a look at this in morning and see what might work best for me and let you know. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. That worked a treat. Taking this a stage further and I appreciate this may not be using function.. what if I wanted to highlight a range of cells and have the characters stripped out of them as opposed to running a calculation next to them to do that?

Comment: See method added in above.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a User-Defined-Function - look at [This Link](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html) to get the basics on how to create a UDF, but basically, open the VBA code-edit, insert a module, and then paste in the following - it should work and you can try to interpret the code (It's fairly easy to get what it's doing)

```
Function WBSReplace(x As String) As String
x = Replace(x, "/", "")
x = Replace(x, "-", "")
x = Replace(x, ".", "")
x = Replace(x, " ", "")
WBSReplace = x
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of that into VBA, but it won't be prettier nor simpler or easy to reuse. The issue is that VBA code is bound to one workbook and if you want to reuse your VBA Code, you will either have to copy-paste it or you will have to write complex copy paste logic that does it for you. In any case, your life will probably be harder than it is right now. But since you asked for it, here's the VBA code for it:

```
Public Function WBSReplace(rng As Range) As String
    WBSReplace = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(rng.Value, "/", ""), ".", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
End Function
```

In your VBA Editor click "Insert" -> "New module" and paste that code. Then, you will be able to use the function `WBSReplace` much like you mentioned it in your question, but, as said before, you will have to copy-paste that VBA code to every workbook that you wish to use it in.

Comment: Possibly put the UDF in a [Personal Macro Workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566).